# Why do I keep getting Downvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

Well, I know about the [*Downvoting a question and not explaining why?*](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/downvoting-a-question-and-not-explaining-why), and I'm ok with that.

> - **Nothing constructive to say**. If a user doesn't feel like there is anything for them to suggest in order to improve a question they
>     may not see the point in down voting. If a user just going to tell you
>     "I think your question is bad and here's why", and there's nothing you
>     can do to improve that, then that comment will probably just irritate
>     the question asker.
> - **Avoid a confrontation with the asker.** Some users will get really hostile when you down vote a question, and may even insult the
>     down voter. This situation happens more often than you'd think ([it
>     happened earlier today in fact](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/downvoting-a-question-and-not-explaining-why)), and I can't blame a user for not
>     wanting to deal with that.
>
> The main thing to remember is that a down vote is **not** a close
>   vote. I down vote questions all the time which I don't think are good
>   questions, but are still perfectly on-topic for the site. So just
>   because your question is getting down voted doesn't mean it's going to
>   get closed.

*My question is, if there is a specific reason to keep getting DV on the question "[Can a Champion jungle effectively without Smite?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59510/can-a-champion-jungle-effectively-without-smite)"* *****

**Maybe a chance in the patch made it look like a silly question. How could I improve it to be a better fit to the site?**

Comment: [This question got *two* downvotes, one a couple days ago, another on March 28th, 2012.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/59510/timeline) Is there really a problem here?

Comment: @badp Actually 3 downvotes ;) you forgot the one on 23 may. But i'm thinking the one today is just due to him linking to his question here on meta.

Comment: @Lyrion [The third downvote happened ~8 minutes after my comment. ;)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/12936/michel?tab=reputation)

Comment: Reminder: It takes **five** down votes to offset the positive effects of **one** up vote. If you have a net positive score, it is literally impossible that a question is a net negative to your reputation. You should *ignore* those down votes. You've asked about this before, and [so have other people.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/why-dont-we-require-a-down-voting-reason) I'd advise you to read those other discussions on the subject as well. Not every down vote is feedback *for you, about a thing which you can fix*. **THEY ARE NOT PERSONAL, so stop taking them that way.**

Answer (score 2):

You've got a grand total of three down votes on the question, and 8 up votes which means a lot more people think it is good than bad. Not to mention those down votes came over a spread of time (a long period of time, to boot!)

Honestly, I think you are worrying over spilled milk at this point. You've gained much more reputation than you have lost, and in the grand scheme of Arqade, I don't think there is really anything happening that has a clear explanation, other than a couple people didn't like it for whatever reason.

In this case especially, I really wouldn't worry about the down votes, and instead would focus on the much larger number of up votes, and leave this particular case as a series of unconnected events that don't have any real worry in them. Down votes happen to everyone, and worrying over them like this helps to only stress yourself out unnecessarily.

Comment: the point wasn't much about the reputation itself. But for me, if a question that old start getting DV once or twice per month and no UV to back it up. There's something wrong with the question itself. So, I want to fix it. I didn't saw the last updates, and what I saw didn't "invalidated" the question itself. But, in my POV there is something wrong for me to keep getting DV on this question. If not, why is it getting periodic DV ?

Comment: Like I said, it got three. Over a very long period.  It's not even one or two a month. I don't think it is a bad question, or anything that really needs you to be this concerned.